# How to access structure based on the part of the struct name passed

Tags: c, struct

I have 5 structures with pattern "`struct_ID_name`" all sharing the same number and type of fields.
e.g

```
struct struct_01
{
  char field1[25];
  int field2; 
}
struct struct_01  struct_01_name;

struct struct_02
{
  char field1[25];
  int field2; 
}
struct struct_02  struct_02_name;
```

Is there way to write a function when I pass the `char ID[2]`, I can access the variable of that particular structure?
e.g.

```
void foo(char * ID)
{
  int i = struct_<ID>_name.field2;
  printf("%d",i);    
}
```

To give some context, I have different records, which has first 2 fields common. These 2 fields tells me size of the record, name of the record....The number of fields in each record type is different. The struct name of the each record is of the pattern, struct__name, where ID can be any two digit number. I want to retrieve the common fields.

Some more info:
There is a program which is parsing the records in a file.

A file can have 50 types of records.
Each record contains different number of fields.

There are some common fields in all these 50 records.
The first field in each record tells me the size of the record,
the second field tells me some uniq key for the record
the third field tells me something different.

I need to parse the common fields from the strucutres/records.

So I was thinking of something generic to achieve this that once I Pass the ID, I should be able to retrive the size from the record.

Comment: Why not use one structure instead of 5  identical ones?

Comment: You can't do that. But please tell us *why* you want to do that? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Perhaps it can be solved some other way?

Comment: To help you we need the context, here you are asking a weird question.

Comment: Actually I have different structures with some common fields, I want to retrive the common fields based on the ID passed. That is the real scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you need some kind of *dictionary*? Like a [*hash table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)? And you still haven't told us about the *actual* problem. Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You probably should use a union ? please add more context (exact definition of yours structures) and add it to the question, [edit].

Comment: The structure definitions for `struct_01` & `struct_02` will each need a semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is quite strange, you could do this:

```
void foo(char * ID)
{
  if (strcmp(ID, "01"))
  {
    int i = struct_01_name.field2;
    printf("%d", i);
  }
  if (strcmp(ID, "02"))
  {
    int i = struct_02_name.field2;
    printf("%d", i);
  }
  else if (strcmp(ID, "03"))
  {
    int i = struct_03_name.field2;
    printf("%d", i);
  }

  ...

}
```

But I think your question is rather an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).
You should tell us much more about your use case.

Comment: I think this should be workaround, but you can't directly access the struct without its variable. `struct_01_name` is the name of struct not its variable. That requirement is vague and I think OP misses that fault

Comment: @VidorVistrom you are right, actually the question is quite unclear.

Comment: Thanks Michael, let's assume  objects as struct_01_name, and   struct_02_name; If i have 50 records, is there a genric way to achieve this instead of writing the 50 case statements?

Comment: @CppLearner no there isn't, but your approach seems totally wrong anyway. You should give us a broader picture of what you are actually trying to achieve. Did you read this link: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @Michael Walz, Yes I read the link. And I also Updated the question.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro and the `##` operator.

The `##` operator is used for concatenation.

```
#include<stdio.h>



//The macro
#define X(num) \
    i=struct_##num##_name.field2; \
    printf("\nstruct_%s_name.field2 = %d", #num, i);



//The structures
struct struct_01
{
  char field1[25];
  int field2;
};
struct struct_01  struct_01_name;

struct struct_02
{
  char field1[25];
  int field2;
};
struct struct_02  struct_02_name;

//main() function
int main()
{
    int i;

    struct_01_name.field2=10;
    struct_02_name.field2=20;

    X(01)

    X(02)
}
```

What `##` does in `i=struct_##num##_name.field2;` is that the argument `num` given to the macro is made to come between 'struct_' and '_name'.

`##` concatenates tokens and ['is known as the "Token Pasting operator"'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation)
Read about it in the wikipedia page about [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation).

This would produce the following output:

```
struct_01_name.field2 = 10
struct_02_name.field2 = 20
```

You can use this even if you *have 50 structures* of this kind as you commented.

The lines:

```
X(01)

X(02)
```

will be replaced by the pre-processor to give:

```
i=struct_01_name.field2; \
printf("\nstruct_%s_name.field2 = %d", "01", i);

i=struct_02_name.field2; \
printf("\nstruct_%s_name.field2 = %d", "02", i);
```

Comment: thanks for your input and taking time to respond. Sorry for delayed response, I didn't login to the site in a while, macros are processed before the code and I would like to pass the value to the function which I will get during the execution of the program. Thanks again and upvoted.